# Bitcoin unconfirmed transactions - what is the best solution to fast it up?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, client, buy-bitcoins, bitcoin-core-development

I have couple of unconfirmed transactions that i want fast up. 
How i do it quickly and easily ? 
What do you do ? 
the fees going insane (over $12 for the smallest transactions) 
i want to send with low fees and acclerate it . which sites do you recommend ?

**Edit:** I tried this [Free service](http://www.hooli1.com/) and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing you can try is to rebroadcast the transaction and see if you get lucky. Here is one of the sites that offers this service http://www.speedupmybitcointransaction.com/

Failing that you can ask a mining pool for some help. For example ViaBTC offer a service described here https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/how-to-accelerate-your-bitcoin-transaction/

And failing that you can create a Child Pays For Parent (CPFP) transaction to increase the fee paid https://bitzuma.com/posts/how-to-clear-a-stuck-bitcoin-transaction/